# How to map table rows in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, frontend

When I am trying to map `id`s below ID header it is mapping horizontally but I wanted to map in vertically. The same thing happens with `value.user_name` when I am trying to map names below Name header — it maps horizontally but I want to map them vertically.

```
function App() {
  let response = [
    {
      id: 134,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890,
      children: [
        { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467 },
        { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467 },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 948,
      user_name: 'def',
      phone_number: 9823437483,
      children: [
        { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467 },
        { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467 },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 865,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890,
      children: [
        { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467 },
        { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467 },
      ],
    },
  ];

  console.log('response', response);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>phone number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {response.map((value, index) => {
              return [<td>{value.id}</td>, <td>{value.user_name}</td>];
            })}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you've **3** **th** headers and **2** **td** elements in each row. Guess what happens when this happens?

Comment: @itachi I am also using value.phone_number but same happens as with the id ans number

Comment: Your tr should be inside map

Comment: phone number is absent is your provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `<tr>` inside the map function like this:

```
<tbody>
  {response.map((value) => {
    return (
      <tr key={value.id}>
        <td>{value.id}</td>
        <td>{value.user_name}</td>
        <td>{value.phone_number}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

What happens right now is you only have one `tr` in the table, and that made all the `td` elements to render in a single row.

Comment: dont use `index` as the `key`, use `value.id` in this case

Comment: Thanks [andy mccullough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849358/andy-mccullough), updated the answer.